# limit on how many times a user can call a firebase onCall function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a couple of onCall firebase functions, is there a way to set a limit ex. 5 times per minute  on how many times a user can call these functions in case someone figures out the url and continuously sends fakes calls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no configurable limit to the number of times a function may be called.  You will have to implement that limitation yourself inside the function if you want to stop the user from doing something more frequently than you want.

Comment: is there a default limit per user?

Comment: There are no limits at all (until you refuse to pay your bill, or you exceed the bandwith limit).  The system will serve them as fast as possible.  The system limits are documented here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#rate_limits

Comment: my worry is that someone could send thousands of requests to the onCall functions. does firebase have a way of filtering out these malicious calls or would it still charge for the function trigger?

Comment: Yes, this is a very common concern for all cloud-hosted services that allow traffic from the internet.  As I said, there is no configuration for this.  If you suspect abusive behavior, contact Firebase support directly: https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support